# How to repositioned compass in Google Map Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-compose

I would like move map compass icon from one position to another in Google Map compose Android Kotlin?
I am trying to find a way where if old code may work in new compose. But, unfortunately there is no any work around.

I did try with old findViewByTag method. But there is not work around. I do not know how to use it.